# Topology on tensor product

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $A$ a $R$-algebra endowed with the $r_0$-adic topology for an ideal $r_0 \subset R$ and $B$ a $R$-algebra endowed with the $r_0$-adic topology for an ideal $r_0' \subset R$. Is there any way to endow $A \otimes_R B$ with an adic topology ?

Comment: Generally, tensor products do not behave well with topologies. However, this issue has been recently studied by Clausen and Scholze. Their solution is condensed rings, and if I remember correctly this would be solved with solid theory. The following notes could be a good starting point: https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf

Comment: Yes I know about this :) but I thought I've read somewhere that in the case I described we can endow a topology on the tensor product such that the multiplication is continuous ?